# Right not working in navbar

Tags: php, html, css

everything worked out great until this morning but I can't find out what is causing this problem.

The problem:
I need a search bar on the right of my nav items but it doesn't want to go to the right side.

The HTML(PHP):

```
<!-- HEADER
    ================================================== -->
<header class="header-type-5">
    <div class="background-header"></div>
    <div class="slider-header">
        <!-- Top of pages -->
        <div id="top" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'header_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } elseif($theme_options->get( 'header_layout' ) == 4) { echo 'fixed3 fixed2'; } elseif($theme_options->get( 'header_layout' ) == 3) { echo 'fixed2';  } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
            <div class="background-top"></div>
            <div class="background">
                <div class="shadow"></div>
                <div class="pattern">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                             <!-- Header Left -->
                             <div class="col-sm-4" id="header-left">        
                                  <?php if ($logo) { ?>
                                  <!-- Logo -->
                                  <div class="logo"><a href="<?php echo $home; ?>"><img src="<?php echo $logo; ?>" title="<?php echo $name; ?>" alt="<?php echo $name; ?>" /></a></div>
                                  <?php } ?>
                             </div>

                            <!-- Header Right -->
                            <div class="col-sm-8" id="header-right">
                                 <?php 
                                 $top_block = $modules->getModules('top_block');
                                 if( count($top_block) ) { 
                                    foreach ($top_block as $module) {
                                        echo $module;
                                    }
                                 } ?>
                                 <?php echo $currency.$language; ?>


                                 <!-- <a href="<?php echo $account; ?>" class="my-account"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></a> -->
                                                                                                 <div class="links">
                                        <a class="l-a" href="index.php?route=account/account">Mijn Account</a>
                                        <a class="l-s" href="index.php?route=checkout/cart">Winkelwagen</a>
                                        <a class="l-c" href="index.php?route=checkout/checkout">Afrekenen</a>
                                  </div>
                                <?php echo $cart; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <style>
                        .sexy_line { 
                            height: 1px;
                            background: white;
                            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 100% 0, from(#222222), to(#222222), color-stop(50%, white));

                        }
                    </style>
                    <div class="sexy_line"></div>
                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 4 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 5 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 6 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 9 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 14 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 19 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 29) { ?>
                    <div class="container container-megamenu2">
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php 
                    $menu = $modules->getModules('menu');
                    if( count($menu) ) { ?>
                         <div class="megamenu-background">
                              <div class="">
                                   <div class="overflow-megamenu container">
                                    <?php 
                                    if(count($menu) > 1) echo '<div class="row mega-menu-modules">';
                                    $i = 0;

                                    foreach ($menu as $module) {
                                         if($i == 0 && count($menu) > 1) echo '<div class="col-md-3">';
                                         if($i == 1 && count($menu) > 1) echo '<div class="col-md-9">';
                                             echo $module;
                                        if(count($menu) > 1 && ($i == 0 || $i == 1)) echo '</div>';
                                        if(count($menu) > 1 && $i == 1) echo '</div>';
                                        $i++;
                                    } ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php } elseif($categories) { ?>
                    <div class="megamenu-background">
                         <div class="">
                              <div class="overflow-megamenu container">
                                <div class="container-megamenu horizontal">
                                    <div class="megaMenuToggle">
                                        <div class="megamenuToogle-wrapper">
                                            <div class="megamenuToogle-pattern">
                                                <div class="container">
                                                    <div><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
                                                    Navigation
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="megamenu-wrapper">
                                        <div class="megamenu-pattern">
                                            <div class="container">
                                                <ul class="megamenu shift-up">
                                                    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                                                    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                                                    <li class="with-sub-menu hover"><p class="close-menu"></p><p class="open-menu"></p>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $category['href'];?>"><span><strong><?php echo $category['name']; ?></strong></span></a>
                                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><span><strong><?php echo $category['name']; ?></strong></span></a>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                        <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
                                                        <?php 
                                                            $width = '100%';
                                                            $row_fluid = 3;
                                                            if($category['column'] == 1) { $width = '220px'; $row_fluid = 12; }
                                                            if($category['column'] == 2) { $width = '500px'; $row_fluid = 6; }
                                                            if($category['column'] == 3) { $width = '700px'; $row_fluid = 4; }
                                                        ?>
                                                        <div class="sub-menu" style="width: <?php echo $width; ?>">
                                                            <div class="content">
                                                                <p class="arrow"></p>
                                                                <div class="row hover-menu">
                                                                    <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($category['children']);) { ?>
                                                                    <div class="col-sm-<?php echo $row_fluid; ?> mobile-enabled">
                                                                        <div class="menu">
                                                                            <ul>
                                                                              <?php $j = $i + ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column']); ?>
                                                                              <?php for (; $i < $j; $i++) { ?>
                                                                              <?php if (isset($category['children'][$i])) { ?>
                                                                              <li><a href="<?php echo $category['children'][$i]['href']; ?>" class="main-menu"><?php echo $category['children'][$i]['name']; ?></a></li>
                                                                              <?php } ?>
                                                                              <?php } ?>
                                                                            </ul>
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <?php } ?>
                                                    </li>
                                                    <?php } ?>
                                                </ul>
                                                <!-- Search -->
                                 <div class="search_form">
                                    <div class="button-search"></div>
                                    <input type="text" class="input-block-level search-query" name="search" placeholder="<?php echo str_replace('...', '', $search); ?>" id="search_query" value="" />

                                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'quick_search_autosuggest' ) != '0') { ?>
                                        <div id="autocomplete-results" class="autocomplete-results"></div>

                                        <script type="text/javascript">
                                        $(document).ready(function() {
                                            $('#search_query').autocomplete({
                                                delay: 0,
                                                appendTo: "#autocomplete-results",
                                                source: function(request, response) {       
                                                    $.ajax({
                                                        url: 'index.php?route=search/autocomplete&filter_name=' +  encodeURIComponent(request.term),
                                                        dataType: 'json',
                                                        success: function(json) {
                                                            response($.map(json, function(item) {
                                                                return {
                                                                    label: item.name,
                                                                    value: item.product_id,
                                                                    href: item.href,
                                                                    thumb: item.thumb,
                                                                    desc: item.desc,
                                                                    price: item.price
                                                                }
                                                            }));
                                                        }
                                                    });
                                                },
                                                select: function(event, ui) {
                                                    document.location.href = ui.item.href;

                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                focus: function(event, ui) {
                                                    return false;
                                                },
                                                minLength: 2
                                            })
                                            .data( "ui-autocomplete" )._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
                                              return $( "<li>" )
                                                .append( "<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )
                                                .appendTo( ul );
                                            };
                                        });
                                        </script>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                 </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                    <?php if($theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 4 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 5 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 6 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 9 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 14 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 19 || $theme_options->get( 'megamenu_type' ) == 29) { ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php 
                    $menu2 = $modules->getModules('menu2');
                    if( count($menu2) ) { 
                         echo '<div class="overflow-menu2">';
                        foreach ($menu2 as $module) {
                            echo $module;
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                    } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php $slideshow = $modules->getModules('slideshow'); ?>
    <?php  if(count($slideshow)) { ?>
    <!-- Slider -->
    <div id="slider" class="<?php if($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 1) { echo 'full-width'; } elseif($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 4) { echo 'fixed3 fixed2'; } elseif($theme_options->get( 'slideshow_layout' ) == 3) { echo 'fixed2'; } else { echo 'fixed'; } ?>">
        <div class="background-slider"></div>
        <div class="background">
            <div class="shadow"></div>
            <div class="pattern">
                <?php foreach($slideshow as $module) { ?>
                <?php echo $module; ?>
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
</header>
```

(The "search_form" div doesn't work)

The CSS part:

```
/* @group  Search */

 @media(max-width: 991px){
      #top .search_form {
           padding: 0px;
           padding-top:0px;
           vertical-align: top;
           width: 100%;
           position: absolute;
           display: none;
      }
      #top .search_form input {
           padding: 11px 35px 10px 20px;
           margin: 0px;
           height: 40px;
           width: 230px;
           font-size: 12px;
           display: none;
      }
      .search_form .button-search,
      .search_form .button-search2 {
           font-family: FontAwesome;
           position: absolute;
           right: 45px;
           top: 10px;
           cursor: pointer;
           font-size: 16px;
           line-height: 16px;
           font-weight: 400;
           color: #333;
           -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
           -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
           display: none;
      }
 }

#top .search_form {
    margin: 6px 26px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 170px;
    position: absolute !important;
                       right:0px;
}

     .header-type-2 #top .search_form {
          width: auto !important;
          max-width: 270px;
          display: block;
     }

    #top .search_form input {
        padding: 11px 35px 10px 20px;
        margin: 0px;
        height: 40px;
        width: 230px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

         .search-type-2 #top .search_form input {
              -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
              -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
              box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.06);
         }

         .search-type-3 #top .search_form input {
              border-radius: 0px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
              -moz-border-radius: 0px;
         }

         .search-type-4 #top .search_form input {
              border-radius: 8px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
              -moz-border-radius: 8px;
         }

         .search-type-5 #top .search_form input {
              border-radius: 4px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
              -moz-border-radius: 4px;
         }

         .search-type-7 #top .search_form input {
              border-radius: 2px;
              -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
              -moz-border-radius: 2px;
         }

         .search-type-6 #top .search_form input {
              -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04), inset 0px 3px 8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
              -moz-box-shadow:    1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04), inset 0px 3px 8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
              box-shadow:         1px 1px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.04), inset 0px 3px 8px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
         }

    .search_form .button-search,
    .search_form .button-search2 {
        font-family: FontAwesome;
        position: absolute;
        right: 45px;
        top: 10px;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 16px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #333;
        -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
        -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    }

        .search_form .button-search:before,
        .search_form .button-search2:before {
            content: "\f002";
        }

    /* @end */
```

I hope someone knows what is causing this problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please paste the real code not patebin's as a pastebin can be deleted while the question may remain. Then the question becomes useless to other seeing it later

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Added the real code